# html can't find image's source when I use EJS for filling the src=""

Tags: html, node.js, express, server, ejs

Basically the think that I'm trying to do is saving the images names to database and using those names for displaying them in the web page.

But i'm encountering a problem with displaying images in html!

In database the informtaion like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULcpw.png)

And the server part of the code is like that.

```
router.use(express.static('./public'));
router.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, './uploads')));

router.get('/img', (req,res,next) => {
Content.findById('62d2bfce53f33f2eed033fba')
    .then(result => {
        const nameOfImg =  result.img[0].name;
        res.locals['name'] = nameOfImg;
        res.render('createPage');
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

This is working...

```
<img src="images/2022-07-16T13-40-30.352Z104879.jpg">
```

But not this.

```
<img src="images/<%= name %>">
```

By the way <%= name %> is working fine

I added some new screenshots about the problem
When I use EJS, i'm having a problem with GET method
[while using <%= name %>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLXFO.png)

And this is when i type image's path with manually.
[image is visible right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idLek.jpg)

Comment: Can you describe the error in more detail than just "is not working", please?

Comment: Please show the output EJS creates for `<img src="images/<%= name %>">`. You'll probably see the problem immediately because it won't match `<img src="images/2022-07-16T13-40-30.352Z104879.jpg">`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen. Sir, i apologize for the explaining part. I'm very new at this. The problem is the image doesn't open when i try to type image's path, src="" part of <img> attribute with EJS. Is there any solution exist for this problem that i don't now? And how can i fix this?

Comment: @ggorlen. Sir, I edited my question and i added screenshots about outputs, errors. I hope, I did truly understand your question. And lastly, why they don't match? What are the differences?

Comment: Please no [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)--it's so much easier to validate that two strings are different when they're as text. In a screenshot there's no way to 100% verfiy--things can _look_ close but be slightly different. In this case, it's plainly obvious that the two strings are completely different. One ends in something like J527104879 and the other ends in 364Z104879.

Comment: @ggorlen 
I solved the problem. I was adding the date to the beginning of the original name of the file while saving it to the local file and I was doing the same when adding it to the database. Obviously these two times cannot be the same. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655198/17396626):

```html
<img src="" id="whatever_you_want">
```

```js
//after getting the image in your js:
const image = document.getElementById("whatever_you_want");
image.src = image_name;
```

It could also have to be with the image path in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLXFO.png): are you sure it's correct? The "/create" seems out of place, but I might be wrong.

Comment: names of the files were different from each other. I fixed it. Thank you.